# FileHelpers: Optional fields in non-quoted CSV

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) to import data from a CSV file. Problem is, some versions of the CSV file have more fields than others.

As such, I have marked the fields that are sometimes missing as being optional, but this does not seem to work as instead of just ignoring when fields are missing (which it seems to do ok) it is also always chopping the last character off of the last field that is present.

For example...

- a row containing "ABC,DEF,GHI" (without the quotes) imports as "ABC", "DEF" & "GHI"
- a row containing "ABC,DEF" (again without the quotes) imports as "ABC" & "DE"

My record format is defined as follows...

```
[DelimitedRecord(@",")]
public class RecordFormat {

    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public String FirstValue;

    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public String SecondValue;

    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public String OptionalValue;

}
```

Can anybody suggest what it is I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like a bug in which seems to be fixed in the latest version 2.9.9

See link at http://www.filehelpers.com/forums/

Comment: Thank you. It indeed appears fixed in the latest release, I have been looking for a later release than 2.0.0.0 for some time. Only problem now is I have to restest everything against the new version (there are a lot of imports). M.

Comment: Any idea where I can download the latest source code? I cannot seem to find anywhere within the teamcity.codebetter site and the source forge project referenced in the readme seems to be stuck at v2.0.0.0

Comment: Please put the actual answer in your answer. Links go out of date.